# How - code will not execute until the data is added to the ClientDataSet and table Jvdbgrid1

Tags: delphi

I have a problem. I need to secure the code before executing until I load the data in ClientDataSet. The code is under the ButtonClick button. Below I have a security - the code will not execute until I load the data from the file, but the data is not immediately added to ClientDataSet and at that time ButtonClik displays an error message because I am referring to data that is not yet in the ClientDataSet and table.

I need this just like below Only the code will not execute until the data is added to the ClientDataSet and table

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if assigned(self.idictionary) then
  begin
      // Code to execute when data is in ClientDataSet and in the table
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Back to posting on this account?

Comment: Test if the dataset is "active".

Answer (score -2):

Some idea of one procedure :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if assigned(self.idictionary) then
  begin
    tThread.createanonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      while notdatainClientDataSet do begin
        sleep(1);
      end;    
      TThread.synchronize(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          // Code to execute when data is in ClientDataSet and in the table
        end); 
  end).start;
end;
```

Comment: Could you simple write it? underscore `notdatainClientDataSet`